# Magento - users can see others data

Tags: security, validation, magento, cookies

We have a Magento store and sometimes when users login it authenticates with someone elses user information.

When the user goes into my account they can see the order details of another customer.

I have found a forum that said to activate the Validate HTTP_USER_AGENT and Validate REMOTE_ADDR values under the Session Validation settings but we are still seeing the issue.

Does anyone have any ideas of what may be causing this issue?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

George

Answer (score 9):

I never really took the time to properly debug this, but some time ago we had an almost identical problem. Eventually it looked like that when `System > Configuration > Web > Use SID on Frontend` is enabled and you also have `Magento Enterprise Full Page Cache` enabled it sometimes saved the `SID` within cached templates. When other users clicked the link with the incorrect SID they sort of took over that session.

After disabled the SID option, we never had the problem again.
Perhaps not a real answer, but maybe valuable information for you.

Comment: I replicated session collision due to this setting. Visit a URL that does not match Magento's base_url causing it to embed the SID in links (ex. set the base_url to https:/example.com but visit through https:/www.example.com). It uses different SID for https & http, so only collides user data @ the https URL. After copying the URL w/ SID, save it somewhere, then log in. Then clear cookies, and visit the URL with the SID (from any computer). You successfully hijacked a session.

Comment: I was having this exact issue, just set the SID to NO, will see how that works. Magento CE 1.9.1. With FPC.